# Cannot import com.google.android.libraries.(anything)

Tags: android-studio, import, maps

I am trying to add a maps activity to my android project using android studio, and I copied the code from developer.google.com which contains the documentation for retrieving the current location. But there in the import part there are some lines

```
import com.google.android.libraries.(something)
```

which is giving the error even though I edited the dependencies in build.gradle, but still it is not working

```
cannot resolve symbol libraries
```

any suggestions, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `.gradle`and `.idea`folder and sync the project again.

You can find above files in Project Window on the left side of IDE